# interpreting the curve of intersection

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definition

I would like to understand the idea of a 'curve of intersection' in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Say we are given a surface $z = x^{\frac{1}{3}}y^{\frac{1}{3}}$ and a plane $y = x$. Then the curve of intersection is obtained by substituting $y=x$ into $z = x^{\frac{1}{3}}y^{\frac{1}{3}}$, thus we get $z = x^{\frac{2}{3}}$. As I understand, this curve is in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, so would the curve of intersection be given as the following set  $$\bigg\{ (x,y,z): z = x^{\frac{1}{3}}y^{\frac{1}{3}},~ y = x ~\text{ and } ~z = x^{\frac{2}{3}} \bigg\} $$
or can we simply note that it is the set of points which satisfy $z = x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ and hence immediately consider it as a projection on the z-x plane, which is the curve $z = x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ in the z-x plane?

Are both of these interpretations valid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Neither interpretation is correct. The curve of intersection is: $\mathcal{C} = \left\{(x,y,z): z = (xy)^{1/3}, x = y\right\} = \left\{(t,t,t^{2/3}): t \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$

Comment: It seems like your $\mathcal{C}$ is the same as the first set I gave, without $z = x^{\frac{2}{3}}$, I can see that that is redundant. What is you interpretation of substituting $y=x$ into $z = (xy)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ to get $z = x^{\frac{2}{3}}$? Can this not be interpreted as the curve of intersection projected onto the z-x plane? If not, then how would you interpret $z = x^{\frac{2}{3}}$?